# Android app stack is not clearing

Tags: android, android-intent

in my android app i wrote a below code to clear the stack of the activities, but this code is not working, so i request you to provide me working snippets on this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfile.this, Login.class)
        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanking you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If current Activity is A and you wants to launch B Activity, also, C and D paused in background, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP will finish C and D but not A.

there is a workaround can let you finish A activity. Create a "static" Handler that can do finish() while receive message in A activity, then sendMessage using static Handler from A while B activity started.

Answer (score 0):

In API level 11 a new Intent Flag was added : `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` Try this flag. Example :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfile.this, Login.class)
        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hi harshit, thanks for your replay. My app minimum API level is 9, i cant able to change that to api level 11, please help me to achieve this in api level 9

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActivityName.this.finish().

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfile.this, Login.class)
        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
  YourActivityName.this.finish();
```